# Select and add values from one dataframe to another in python

Tags: python, dataframe, select

I'd like to add the coordinates 'latitude'and 'longitude' to the dataframe df_comp based on the lookuptable df_pc. The real tables are much larger. These are examples. 
How do I look up the right latitude and longitude coordinates in df_pc and add it to df_comp? Thx

```
df_pc=pd.DataFrame({'Postalcode':[1000, 1100, 1200, 2000],
             'Latitude':[52.34, 53.65, 56.78, 58.79 ],
             'Longitude':[6.67, 6.79, 7.32, 7.85]})
df_comp = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['company 1','company 2', 'company 3','company 4' ],
                    'Postalcode_comp':[1100, 1100, 1000, 2000],
                   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge two pandas dataframes like that:

```py
df_comp = df_comp.merge(df_pc, left_on='Postalcode_comp', right_on='Postalcode')
```

This will "combine" the dataframes based on the common values of *Postalcode_comp* column of `df_comp` and *Postalcode* column of `df_pc`.

You might want to pass *how="left"* in order to keep all rows of the `df_comp` dataframe, because the default merge (*how="inner"*) will only keep the intersection. See more documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html